# iOS Compass vs independent developer versions

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, core-motion

I can't seem to manage to make my compass application function anywhere near as smoothly as Apple's, and I haven't seen any compass applications from independent developers that don't lag and sometimes jump erratically like mine does.

Is there any open source that demonstrates how to achieve such fluidity? Accuracy isn't quite so important, but smooth animation is.

Comment: Apple has lots of sample code about animation.

Comment: I know. Thanks for your comment, but you're pointing me in a very general direction. Do you have any specific tutorials or code samples in mind? I'd love to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general direction advice:

- Easy: Apply a low pass filter to discard erratic readings.
- Tricky: The compass updates slower than the gyroscope yaw, so you can measure the drift between compass updates to improve the response. [Sample code](http://www.sundh.com/blog/2011/09/stabalize-compass-of-iphone-with-gyroscope/).
- Trickier: The proper way to fuse the gyroscope and the compass would be using a Kalman filter, but it isn't trivial. There is a talk about it at http://talkminer.com/viewtalk.jsp?videoid=C7JQ7Rpwn2k